# Edit HTML Snippet Suggestion VSCode

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, snippets

I really do not understand this snippets and Emmets things and my English is very bad.

when i hit <kbd>space</kbd> in blank HTML file a windows is shown and when i hit <kbd>enter</kbd> write HTML starting point and its good thing

but i hit <kbd>space</kbd> in every where in HTML file and windows is shown and its annoying

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X4Vk.jpg)

Comment: Why are you writing text like this in an HTML file?

Comment: @Dave for example i write text to show my problem , when i create a button and name it "download file" i use space and windows its popup every time i use space in every where in document.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is HTML-CSS-Class-Completion extension by disabling that back to normal.

[Always suggests "html" Intellisense · Issue](https://github.com/zignd/HTML-CSS-Class-Completion/issues/149)

After a while and several updates VSCode i enable extension for test and problem not back .

Answer (score 0):

You have apparently assigned <kbd>Space</kbd> as the shortcut for "Open User Snippets".

To undo this, open in VSCode the menu
*File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*
(on macOS: *Code > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts*),
find the shortcut relating to Snippets,
right-click it and choose Remove (or Change to a new shortcut).

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F0RQ4.jpg) "Space" only assigned for this